# Android Location Listener not firing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, location

I am trying to detect when the user's current location changes in my android app. The onLocationChanged is not fired however. I tried to implement this in a Fragment btw.

**Fragment:**

```
public class Fragment_Map extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment__live_map, container, false);
        rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // The minimum time (in miliseconds) the system will wait until checking if the location changed
        int minTime = 1000;
        // The minimum distance (in meters) traveled until you will be notified
        float minDistance = 1;
        // Create a new instance of the location listener
        MyLocationListener myLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        // Get the location manager from the system
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Get the criteria you would like to use
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
        // Get the best provider from the criteria specified, and false to say it can turn the provider on if it isn't already
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        // Request location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, minTime, minDistance, myLocListener);

        return rootView;
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {
                Log.d("CHECKLOCA", "fired");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // Do something here if you would like to know when the provider is disabled by the user
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // Do something here if you would like to know when the provider is enabled by the user
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // Do something here if you would like to know when the provider status changes
        }
    }
```

Why isn't the location changed listener firing? Is it because it's a Fragment? In the middle of a Hackathon guys, could you help me resolve this nasty bug?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `GoogleApiClient` to request location and set priority to `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`. You can make your `Fragment` to implement the `callbacks` for `GoogelApiClient` - and then instantiate and connect `GoogleAPIClient` like this:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                .build();
      googleApiClient.connect();
```

Then once your client is connected to the Location Services API, you can then request updates:

```
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
    ...
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(180000); // update interval - eg (3) minutes 
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, myLocListener);

    ...

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Interface like this:

   ```
   public interface OnLocationReceived 
   {
    public void onLocationReceived(LatLng latlong);
    public void onLocationReceived(Location location);
    public void onConntected(Bundle bundle);
    public void onConntected(Location location);
   }
   ```

   2.Put this in `MyLocationListener`

   ```
   @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
   {
     if (!isLocationReceived) {
       mLocationReceived.onConntected(location);
       isLocationReceived = true;
      }
      if (mLocationReceived != null) {
       mLocationReceived.onLocationReceived(location);
      }
      latLong = getLatLng(location);
      if (mLocationReceived != null && latLong != null) {
       mLocationReceived.onLocationReceived(latLong);
      }
   }
   ```